# Multiple values for the same URI parameter

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am creating an API using ORDS (v18.3) via APEX and I need to be able to pass multiple values for the same parameter, eg:

```
https://server-url/resource?id=1&id=2
```

This is a third-party requirement which cannot be changed.

When I try using a URL like this only the first parameter is passed, and the second is stripped away.

Is it possible to do what I need using ORDS?

Comment: There must be some say in URL formation, surely - to concatenate the parameters with the rest of the URL? Any change of replacing punctuation?

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to do some kind of URL rewrite before it gets passed to ORDS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem that I fixed by simply processing the query string.

Created a function:

```
create or replace function array_from_oldschool(p_query_string in varchar2, p_key in varchar2) return apex_t_varchar2 is
  l_ret     apex_t_varchar2 := apex_t_varchar2();
  l_usenext boolean := false;
  l_isval   boolean := false;
  l_arr     apex_t_varchar2;
begin
  l_arr := apex_string.split(p_query_string, '\s*[=&]\s*');
  for i in 1 .. l_arr.count loop
    if l_usenext = true and l_isval = true then
      l_ret.extend;
      l_ret(l_ret.count) := l_arr(i);
      l_usenext := false;
    end if;

    if l_arr(i) = p_key and l_isval = false then
      l_usenext := true;
    end if;

    l_isval := not (l_isval);
  end loop;

  return l_ret;
end;
```

To test: create an ORDS GET service, type PL/SQL

```
declare
  l_arr apex_t_varchar2;
begin
  l_arr := array_from_oldschool(p_query_string => owa_util.get_cgi_env('QUERY_STRING'), p_key => 'id');

  for i in 1 .. l_arr.count loop
    htp.prn(l_arr(i) || ' <br>');
  end loop;
end;
```

Test it: GET testme/old-school?id=1&id=2&id=10&id=100&id=99

Output is:

```
1
2
10
100
99
```

You will need to change a bit of code, going from using owa_util.ident_arr to a TABLE of Varchar2 like apex_T_varchar2. But it should be minimal.

Regards
Olafur

*** EDIT *** 
This function is better since the other one messes up if the query string has empty parameters (i.e. val=&val2=&val4=)

```
create or replace function query_string_array(p_key in varchar2) return apex_t_varchar2 is
  l_query_string apex_t_varchar2;
  l_return       apex_t_varchar2 := apex_t_varchar2();
begin
  l_query_string := apex_string.split(owa_util.get_cgi_env('QUERY_STRING'), '&');
  for i in 1 .. l_query_string.count loop
    if l_query_string(i) like p_key || '=%' then
      if replace(l_query_string(i), p_key || '=', '') is not null then
        l_return.extend;
        l_return(l_return.count) := replace(l_query_string(i), p_key || '=', '');
      end if; --don't add empty/null values
    end if;
  end loop;
  return l_return;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, no one (including Oracle support) was able to give a solution to this. I will award you extra bounty when it allows me!

Comment: No problem, had the same problem (old mod_owa program) and no fix, so I created my own fix. @KrisRice, ORDS could add this kind of support pretty easily for legacy mod_owa programs. Create a parameter type old school owa_util.ident_arr that returns a apex_t_varchar2

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you *can* pass any number of values, but all of them should belong to the same parameter and separated by colon sign. In your case, that would be

```
https://server-url/resource?id=1:2
```

which also means that you'd have to "split" them afterwards, somehow, in order to get separate values.

I used that when I was calling a report (developed by Oracle Reports) from Apex. It wasn't a problem to split those values in its *After parameter form* trigger, but - I don't know whether you can do that in your case.

Hopefully, someone will know better than I do.

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately I have to have the parameters passed separately

Comment: You're welcome. Although Stack Overflow is a great place for discussions, perhaps you'd rather ask Apex-specific questions on Oracle Technology Network Apex forum. People who actually develop Apex answer questions there (along with some true *experts*, not guys like me :)). See what they say.

Comment: @Littlefoot is correct currently ORDS doesn't treat this as an array would have to send in a some delimited values. some javascript in the page could transform. reason is that Array binding from java<>plsql  then process in plsql isn't always simple to understand

Comment: @KrisRice Is there an alternative or work around that you can recommend for allowing the use of multiple parameters with the same name? The API I am writing is following an [international healthcare standard](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html#combining) that requires parameters to be passed in this way.